# Find e-mail addresses of people who downloaded my extension from Web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Suppose I published a free chrome extension to Chrome Web Store.

Is it possible to get a list of e-mail addresses of people who downloaded it?

Comment: No, and thank goodness for that.

Comment: Nominating to reopen: the close reason is clearly wrong. Also, it is a useful question technically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid question. I believe there may be good reasons for obtaining the email address of a chrome extension user for purposes other than SPAM. That being said, there is no way to automatically obtain a users's email. Suggested practices may include:

1) Directly asking the user to input their email.

2) Using the Facebook App flow to ask for permission to read the user's email address, which first notifies the user you are going to access this information.

It might be reasonable to first tell the user what you intend to use their email for (password recovery, notifications, etc).

Comment: If it's anything related to an update of the extension, there are methods within the extension that can alert the information.  If you're trying to establish a dialog, then it should be the user's initiative.  What "good reasons" are you thinking of?

Comment: Sadly, there is a way.

Answer (score 4):

Horrifyingly, yes, there is a way for an extension to obtain the address silently - assuming that the user is signed in into Chrome. It is rather obscure in the docs, though.

Your extension must declare the following permission in the manifest:

```
"permissions" : [
   // ...
   { "identity" : [ "email" ] },
   // ...
 ]
```

Then you can use this:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo) {
  console.log("Nyeh heh heh, your signed-in account's email is " + userInfo.email + "!");
});
```

**However, and thank [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for that**, it will display a permission warning on install:

> Know your email address

..but who reads permission warnings those days?

---

Also, obviously, it will not give you the historical data if you didn't implement collection of those addresses.

And I don't need to explain to you, hopefully, that actually collecting those without explicit user permission (and no, just clicking through the Web Store warning shouldn't count) is malicious and Google may take your extension down.

Comment: This only works when the user is signed in in Chrome.

Comment: Well, my code says that, but perhaps I should add it.